# Questions regarding the submodules of a $\mathbb{F}[X]$-module

Tags: linear-algebra, modules

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be a field and $U= \mathbb{F}^2$. U is equipped with a $\mathbb{F}[X]$-module taking the endomorphism $f : U \to U$ given by the matrix
$F =
\begin{bmatrix}
0 & -2\\
2 & 3 
\end{bmatrix}$.
Find all the sub-$\mathbb{F}[X]$-modules of $V$.

I know how to solve the exercise but still have some issues understanding the whole concept of $\mathbb{F}[X]$-module.

In this example we take
$\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{R}$.
First I will write down the solution.
Let $W$ be a submodule. It's a vectorial space since $U$ is one.
We try to find the submodules by analyzing the dimension of $W$. If $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}W = 1$, then we can write $W = \text{span}(w)$ (Thus $W$ is generated by one single vector)

Let's find the eigenvalues of $f$. After some calculations we find the characteristic polynomial $-3X + X^2 + 4$ which has no roots in $\mathbb{R}$ since $\Delta < 0$. So $f$ has no eigenvalues which leads to the conclusion that there is no $W$ such that $\dim_{\mathbb{R}}W = 1$.
The only submodules of $U$ as a $\mathbb{R}[X]$-module are $(0)$ and $U$ itself.

As I said, I understand the steps in the solutions but I still don't really understand why we have this endomorphism and why it's given by a matrix $F$.

Comment: You started with a field $\Bbb K$ but somewhere in the solution you changed to $\Bbb R$ and used the fact that $X^2 + 1$ has no root in $\Bbb R$. In the end you changed back to $\Bbb K$.

Comment: Oh yes! I’ll change this thanks!

Comment: You need to specify $f$ to turn $\Bbb{F}^2$ into an $\Bbb{F}[X]$-module. How would you define $X\cdot w$ otherwise? The idea is that *any* vector space over $\Bbb{F}$ can be turned into an $\Bbb{F}[X]$-module be selecting *any* endomorphism $f:V\to V$, and then for every $w\in V$ and $p(X)=\sum_{i=0}^n a_iX^i$ letting
$$p(X)\cdot w=\sum_{i=0}^n a_i f^i(w).$$
So in your example we have, among other things
$$X\cdot\binom2 3=\pmatrix{0&-1\cr1&0\cr}\binom 23=\binom{-3}2.$$
With this in place we easily see that a subspace $W\subseteq V$ is a submodule if and only if $f(W)\subseteq W$.

Comment: This question is, in my opinion, more or less a duplicate of either [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1925256/11619) or [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1923895/11619). Most likely there is an even better earlier duplicate.

Comment: [Also](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1942580/11619).

Comment: [Better](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/970419/11619).

Comment: I’ve already read some of these already… but I’ll check it again then, thanks!